# How can I make a select list readonly in Django-widget-tweaks form?

Tags: django-widget-tweaks

With the code below, the control form does get the gray color that is related to non-editable form controls but it is however editable.
I want a select list to show a value that the user can see but not edit.

`

```
{% render_field form.category|attr:value:'car'|append_attr:"readonly:readonly" type="text" placeholder="Category" %}

{% render_field form.category|attr:value:'car'|attr:readonly

{% render_field form.category|attr:value:'car'|attr:readonly:True %}`
```

None of these work. I can click on the select list and it drops down to show option values

I have shown above the lines of code I tried